# Camera is assigned strange ip from router

Tags: ip

I have bought an HIKVISION camera. every time I connect it to my router and try to look at its IP on the router settings I see that the camera got an IP address like this:
fdb8:5412:645f:0:bead:28ff:fe58:e06b

Any idea why?

Comment: What is strange about that IPv6 address?

Comment: why isnt it getting a regular ip address like 10.0.0.50?
I cant connect to the camera without an ip with numbers

Comment: Try not using the router to get the IP address but a network scanner on your machine

Comment: Are you sure the camera shows _only_ that address? I would expect it to show both IPv6 (if SLAAC is working) _and_ IPv4 (if DHCP is working).

Comment: @Chenmunka - Your camera does have an ip address, it is an IPv6 ip address, and I presume it is being assigned a IPv6 address because its been configured that way.

Comment: If you execute `ipconfig` or `ifconfig` on your computer, do you see an IPv6 address with the same prefix `fdb8:5412:645f:0` ?  If so, you should be able to access the camera via it's IPv6 address the same way as you would access it via an IPv4 address.  Note that if access is via a web browser, you would need to enclose the address in square brackets `[...]`.

Comment: you should be able to disable ipv6 either on the camera or on your router. Anyway, if you dont have any other problem than the "strangeness", just live with it and connect to the camera using its name

Answer (score 4):

With the little information you've provided there's nothing strange about that IP. If you're expecting a IPv4 address (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx) it's just that your camera and router are talking to each other using [IPv6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6).

Please be aware that depending on your router configuration your camera might be internet accessible.

As it was pointed out in the comments, assuming you posted the actual IPv6 address, that address would be a [unique local adress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_local_address) which would be the an approximate equivalent of the IPv4 private address ranges (10/8, 172.16/12, 192.168/16). Which should mean it won't be routed on the actual internet (if devices are not misconfigured).

Comment: is there a way to change the ip to ipv4?
because neither my browser nor my montoring app can connect to that camera with ipv6 ip

Comment: @OmerBinyamini - Your browser absolutely can browser/connect to a IPv6 address it does so daily.

Comment: If the OP posted the actual address listed for the device, that is a Unique Local Address which would not be internet accessible.

Comment: Thanks @user4556274 I included that bit in the answer. If you think it's insufficient suggest an edit.

Comment: @OmerBinyamini check your computer configuration whenever it has an IPv6 address (e.g. using `ipconfig`). If it doesn't, that would be the reason you can't connect to the camera. Also check the manual for the device on how to initially set it up and assign an IP.